# Nginx не видит файлы в папке

Tags: nginx

Хочу подключить `freessl` на сайт. Для этого мне надо пройти верификацию Надо чтобы по этим путям были файлы

```
http://xxx.su/.well-known/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y
http://www.xxx.su/.well-known/acme-challenge/bpxL8socCbfycpgSuhWHnuscPKEKhKq9FMLUrzrwP6M
```

Для этого я скачал оба файла в папку `/var/www/html`, и внес правки в конфиг nginx. Почему то при гет-запросе у меня сервер не видит файлы. Отображает ошибку 403. Подскажите что неправильно в моем конфиге?

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/rifc/shared/tmp/sockets/rifc-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name xxx.ru;


  root /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }


  location /.well-known {
     root /var/www/html;
     autoindex on;
   }


try_files $uri @puma;
#  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

В логах у меня следующая ошибка. Говорит что папка не найден файл или директория. Хотя дал права `775` на папку рекурсивно.

```
==> /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/log/nginx.error.log <==
2017/07/26 11:43:56 [error] 3121#3121: *5 open() "/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.163.56.96, server: xxx.ru, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.ru"
```

Comment: nginx botт файл по пути `/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y`, о чём пишет в еррор-логе. нужно проверить есть ли по этому пути что-то и доступно ли это что-то для чтения юзеру от которого запускаются воркеры nginx.

Comment: я дал доступ на всю папку  sudo chmod -R /var/www/html

Comment: просто проверь руками

Comment: Сделал руками.  nano /var/www/html/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y 
 Есть полный доступ. Редактирую от НЕ рута

Comment: /var/www/html/ **.well-known** /acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTj‌​sBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhX‌​a06Y, прочитай, наконец, как работает директива root. и alias.

Comment: @norbornen спасибо) вы были правы. Однако nginx тупо дает файл скачивать. Как сделать чтобы он его как txt открывал в браузере

Comment: зачем и кому понадобится открывать этот файл в браузере?